# How to make a div in a dynamically sized table cell fill the cell

Tags: html, css

I have a royal pain in the butt problem.  I have a page layout where there are two columns to a table.  The right column is always 300px wide, but the left column is to fill the remaining space in the container.  This is easy enough with the following:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width='*'>
    </td>
    <td width='300'>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now, I want the left column to contain a div that has some styling applied to it.  In that styling there is a rule that the width of the div is 300px.  This is fine for the RIGHT column, but I want the left column to be filled by the div.  My instincts tell me to add a style tag with "width: inherit;" but that doesn't work, it simply strips the width altogether.  I believe this to be because CSS doesn't know how to inherit width="*".

So, what is the best way to style this div in the left column such that it fills the TD?  Any width % value is calculated relative to the page, not the container.

My only solution (haven't done this yet) that I can come up with is to resize the TD with CSS whenever the window paints, then the div's style: inherit would work, I believe.  I REALLY don't want to do it that way as I'm praying there's a CSS compliant way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Shoulda tried this sooner.  If you set the position: relative; on the div it works.  The css that automatically sets the width to 300px also sets position: absolute with didn't allow inherit to be relative to the TD.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose a jquery solution (if possible) in your situation:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#td-style-of-your-naming-choice").resize(
          function(){$("#div-id").width($("#td-style-of-your-naming-choice").width();
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question I am getting the the width of the left div is automatically set to 300px (by a stylesheet or something) and that you want it to be the width of the left column instead of 300px.

I think you should try width: auto. width: inherit might to to get the width of the parent (td) which is not set. By default, divs are block elements so will automatically fill their parent. The default width property is auto.

This is not the case if the div is positioned absolutely or the div is floated. In that case you must set a static width.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
        <div style="width:100%">123</div>
    </td>
    <td width='300'>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/LMLbD/

Answer (score 0):

Following worked in IE9:

```
style="width:inherit; height:inherit; position:relative;"
```